# Same producer with different ports can't be load balanced by Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am new to Zuul. I have two producer projects with different ports defined. However, the Zuul always direct to the first project instead of load balancer it. I have succeded once but failed always with nothing changed.

Zuul application.properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=gateway-service-zuul

zuul.routes.producer.path=/producer/**
zuul.routes.producer.service-id=spring-cloud-producer
```

Producer one application.properties

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-producer
server.port=9000
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8760/eureka/
```

Producer two application.properties

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-producer-2
server.port=9001
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8760/eureka/
```

If you change the application.properties of Zuul to:

```
zuul.routes.producer.service-id=spring-cloud-producer-2
```

I am able to direct the traffic to producer-2. It verifies that producer-2 can be run successfully.
I understand that I can use Eureka directly without using path and service-id but I still want to figure this out.

The failed log- you can't see producer-2 in the DynamicServerListLoadBalancer...

```
2021-02-07 18:53:33.943  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/producer/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2021-02-07 18:53:33.943  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/spring-cloud-producer/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2021-02-07 18:53:33.943  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/spring-cloud-producer-2/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2021-02-07 18:53:34.026  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6a4db6dc: startup date [Sun Feb 07 18:53:34 CST 2021]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61d01788
2021-02-07 18:53:34.145  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2021-02-07 18:53:34.542  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: spring-cloud-producer.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2021-02-07 18:53:34.603  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-spring-cloud-producer
2021-02-07 18:53:34.649  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: spring-cloud-producer instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=spring-cloud-producer,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2021-02-07 18:53:34.664  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2021-02-07 18:53:34.712  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: spring-cloud-producer.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2021-02-07 18:53:34.716  INFO 14868 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client spring-cloud-producer initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=spring-cloud-producer,current list of Servers=[localhost:9000],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;  Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:localhost:9000;    Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@3ec2c916
2021-02-07 18:53:35.673  INFO 14868 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: spring-cloud-producer.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2021-02-07 18:57:44.394  INFO 14868 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

Full code can be found from here.. [code](https://github.com/cyx441984694/spring-cloud-zuul)

You comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can use ribbon and add the url list to it:

application.properties in zuul:

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=gateway-service-zuul

zuul.routes.producer.path=/producer/**
zuul.routes.producer.service-id=producer-service

        
producer-service.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
producer-service.ribbon.listOfServers=localhost:9000,localhost:9001
producer-service.ribbon.ConnectTimeout=1000
producer-service.ribbon.ReadTimeout=3000
producer-service.ribbon.MaxTotalHttpConnections=500
producer-service.ribbon.MaxConnectionsPerHost=100

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8760/eureka/
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

All the instances should have the same `serviceId`/ `application.name` and just different ports. Then your request will be load-balanced to one of the service instances that are available for the `serviceId` specified in the request.